# Building a new computer and it is not booting up. Continual 3 BIOS beeps. What should I do?

Tags: memory, bios

I've just built a new computer, but it's not booting. When I press the power button, the BIOS continually beeps in 3's I checked the Intel site and said that's a memory error, so I bought some new memory, but it's giving me the same thing. Anyone know what this means or what I should do?

Using a Intel DP55WB Motherboard with intel Core i5 750 processor. Tried it first with OCZ platinum 4GB, then corsair xms3 4GB.

Answer (score 4):

Did you install the memory in the correct slot?  Look at page 35 of the the [manual](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18131/eng/DP55WB_ProductGuide01_English.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Try it with one stick in the FIRST slot. I imagine you've probably got multiple sticks in multiple slots. Try another stick in that same first slot. If neither works, double-check your motherboard's supported memory list - those usually don't matter, but a few boards are more picky.

Also, you might try re-seating the CPU and testing it with ALL expansion cards removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking the memory part numbers, but your motherboard only supports DDR3 memory less than 1.6V and the two you listed could be 1.7V and 1.65V. Quote from the [product website](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dp55wb/sb/CS-030682.htm): "Using a DIMM with a voltage rating higher than 1.6 V may damage the processor." Are you sure you got the right memory for your motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

If it is 3 short beeps have a look here:

[Computer has three short beeps as it starts](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000996.htm)

Also check this if you get other types of beeps:

[Computer POST / beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently added or tried to add additional memory to the computer and have started getting these beeps. Remove all new memory you've added to the computer. If the computer works fine after removing the new memory you're encountering either an incompatibility or defective new memory.OR

Sometimes when the computer is moved and/or over time a memory stick can become loose causing the computer to be unable to read the memory or get errors as it's reading it. Try fixing this issue by opening the computer removing each of the memory sticks you have in the computer and then placing them back into the computer.
If you have access to another computer that uses the same type of memory try using its known good memory in your computer.OR

If another computers memory works you know that you have bad memory. If another computers memory does not work and it is compatible with your computer unfortunately your motherboard and/or the slots on the motherboard are defective causing it to be unable to properly read the memory, which means the motherboard will have to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the Motherboard Manufacturer, but I'd bet its one of the following:

1. CPU (Bad CPU? Bent Pins? Inserted properly?)
2. Memory (Bad Memory? Wrong Type? Inserted Properly?)
3. Video Card (Bad Video Card? Inserted Properly?)

Remove all three of the following and add them one at a time.

Check if you have the correct type of memory..

Good Luck!